# UL Menu Snap To Links

Tags: jquery, html, css

Curious if there are any ways using css or jquery to make a ul menu snap to the links.

Example: When you scroll through a [Normal UL Menu](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AaLnH) you get cutoff links which can be a bit ugly. I would like the menu to snap to the top of the links.

It should be noted I am already using [JScrollPlane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to stylize my scroll bars, could I add some code to that?

Comment: Looks like there's currently an issue with your first link. Could you try adding the code to http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Seems to work for me. Is it ok now?